# Если m % n == k или m % n == l, то вывести 1, иначе любое другое число

Tags: c++, олимпиада

На вход программе подаются 4 целых числа, по модулю не превосходящие 10^6: m,n,k,l. Если остаток от деления m на n равен k или l, то выведите 1, в противном случае - любое другое число. Условный оператор использовать нельзя!

Я написал такой код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int m, n, k, l;
cin >> m >> n >> k >> l;

cout << ((1 / (((m % (n + 1 / (n + 1))) - k) * ((m % (n + 1 / (n + 1))) - k) + 1)) - 1) * ((1 / (((m % (n + 1 / (n + 1))) - l) * ((m % (n + 1 / (n + 1))) - l) + 1)) - 1) + 1;

return 0;
}
```

Но он проходит только 11 тестов из 13. Я сам заметил, что на случае 0, 0, 0, 0 код выдaёт 1, хотя не должен.
Покажите, пожалуйста, как мне изменить код.

Comment: в задаче `m` и `n`, в решении откуда-то `k,l` еще. Вроде надо к 1 прибавить остатки от деления, и на этом все, или нет?

Comment: а не, просто сложить остатки не получится

Comment: Исправил условие

Comment: Остаток от деления на 0 - спорная вещь. Поэтому, врятли он есть в тестах. А вот, переполнение int при умножениях - запросто.

Comment: в новой постановке надо взять логическое выражение с ИЛИ для проверки остатков деления. Получите булево значение, выполняется хотя бы одно или нет. Далее приведете его к целому. Будет у вас 1 или 0 на выходе. Вот эти деления все зачем вам нужны и +1 какие то? прям вот заголовок прямым текстом в код перевести, без любых дополнительных действий, только любое это всегда 0.

Comment: Собственно `cout << (m % n == k) || (m % n == l);` и вся программа. Единственный вопрос - как обрабатывать ситуацию, если `n==0` - т.к. на ноль делить нельзя программа будет завершаться с исключением. В условии задачи ничего про это не сказано?

Comment: Не нужно вандалить вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, раз `%` можно, а делить на 0 — нет, то воспользуемся сокращенным вычислением логического выражения...

```
int main()
{
    int n, m, k, l;
    cin >> m >> n >> k >> l;
    cout << (n && (m%n-l)*(m%n-k) == 0);
}
```

Можно и отдельно проверять на равенство:

```
cout << (n && (m%n == l || m%n == k));
```

Comment: преобразования типов не очень понятны. может быть проще так : `(m%n-l)*(m%n-k) + 1` ?

Comment: Только если компилятор сначала вычислит `0 &&` и дальше не станет вычислять. А так в любом случае `m%n` если `n==0` даст исключение. И формула при `n==0` выдаст 1, что не является правильным результатом.

Comment: @DmitryK Если компилятор соответствует стандарту, то, вычислив 0, он не станет вычислять то, что справа от `&&`...

Comment: @AlexGlebe Не очень понимаю, как вы хотите сделать. Можно полную строку?

Comment: если остаток равен **l** или **k** то умножение даст ноль и с прибавлением единицы получаем ответ. если остатки другие, то результат больше единицы, что и даст правильный ответ.

Comment: @Harry - спасибо, не знал. Я думал это оптимизатора зависит, а не прописано в стандарте.

Comment: @AlexGlebe А как при этом обработать деление на 0? Мы же не можем просто написать `cout << (m%n-l)*(m%n-k) + 1`?